# At what place did the 5 Aurors in the Intro of Fantastic Beasts get killed?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In the intro of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* you see 5 Aurors who try to infiltrate/investigate a place.

Before they get killed you can see a house/mansion, but what was it?

Grindelwald's house or headquarters?

Some say its Nurmengard Fortress but that is impossible cause Nurmengard Fortress/Prison is way bigger and stands between two big rocks.

Does anyone know what place the Aurors got killed?

Answer (score 2):

**It's left unclear.**

From the script:

> SCENE 1 EXT. SOMEWHERE IN EUROPE--1926--NIGHT
>
> A large, isolated, derelict chateau emerges from the darkness. We
>   focus on a cobbled square outside the building, shrouded in mist,
>   eerie, silent.
>
> Five Aurors stand, wands aloft, tentative as they edge towards the
>   chateau. A sudden explosion of pure white light sends them flying.
>
> We whip around to find their bodies scattered, lying motionless at the
>   entrance to a large parkland. A figure (Grindelwald) enters the frame,
>   his back to the camera; ignoring the bodies, he stares out into the
>   night sky as we pan up towards the moon.

The use of the word chateau suggests that it's in a French-speaking country, and the parkland/cobblestone suggests an old country estate. "Derelict" makes it sound like it's not where Grindelwald lives on a long-term basis; either somewhere he's squatting temporarily or simply somewhere the Aurors tracked him to. But other than that, the location of the attack is left (I would say) deliberately vague.

Comment: @J.P Future films are said to be set in Europe. The second film is already said to in part take place in Paris, France--So it seems like it may get answered at some point! 
https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1587480/fantastic-beasts-2-wont-be-set-entirely-in-paris